# how to check the magento is running on zend server

Tags: magento, zend-server

I am on cent os. I want to install magento on zend server as directed by my TL. I have removed my Apache by command 'yum erase httpd'. later i installed zend server. I verified zend server by running the *http://localhost:10081/zendserver*. It is running.

Later I have downloaded magento and gave permissions to the media, app and etc folders. Then I gave as *http://localhost/magento* then the installation window appeared and I gave the required details.
 so now the magento admin panel is on *http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin* and home page on *http://localhost/magento.* My doubt is, in the browser if i give as just *'localhost'* apache server home pagge is coming. If I give as *localhost:10081* then zend server home page is working.

my zend server document root is /var/www/html. I placed my magento folder there only.

I want a clarity that on which server my magento is running?? Am i cleared apache or not?

Please solve my doubt....

Answer (score 0):

Create one file - info.php and put such code in it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Open

```
 http://localhost:10081/info.php
 http://localhost/info.php
```

Look to SERVER_SOFTWARE variable.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the reply... if i give  http://localhost:10081/info.php it shows  404-URL not found and if i give  http://localhost/info.php, then it shows the php server description and their details.. so is my magneto working on Zend????

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it by using

php phpinfo();

die();

in index.php file at the beginning of file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, don't worry about the fact that this is a little confusing because it happens to all new Zend Server users...

When you install Zend Server what you wind up with is several programs installed:

Web Server: apache (or nginx if you chose that option)
App Server: Zend Server
DB Server: MySQL

My guess is that when you ran your command to remove httpd it removed your executable but left your configuration intact in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf (or the equivalent in your OS)

When Zend Server installed it's apache that process may have picked up your previous configuration.

Check to see if there's anything in etc regarding the httpd.conf and compare the virtual host settings there to what you have in your Zend Server, that may tell you if this is what's happening or if there's something else going on.